# I want to create custom tab bar in android, The tabs must be right-aligned and contents must be at the left-side

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, tabwidget

I need to create a layout in Android having tabs *right-aligned* and the contents must be shown at the *left-side* in **ListView**.

Please help me out by giving your useful suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RelativeLayout for your row items in the listview.
From there you can use

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

in your xml and that will make sure whatever view you put that in will be to the right.

Comment: Ok. So you can still use a RelativeLayout as your base, and right align all your tabs and left align your listview

Comment: Thanks a lot frank will try to sought it out....else you are here to help me out...do have any kind a blog or something where i can get help directly..

Comment: If I helped you please upvote and accept my answer. I try to stay on stackoverflow all the time. However, my blog is mobile.cs.fsu.edu and our direct QA line is mobile.cs.fsu.edu/qa

Comment: can u suggest some simple sort of way through which i can make my tabs vertically align.....

Comment: Put them in a LinearLayout with vertical orientation

Comment: No. I'm not going to spend anymore time on this question, because I have not been getting any points. Sorry.